# EF6 unable to call stored procedure and return complex type

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am in the process of creating classes with all of the database access functions for each of my entities (`GetById`, `Insert`, `Update`, `Delete`, `GetList`).

For my `GetList` functions I always use stored procedures because they can get very complex (I prefer TSQL over Linq) when it comes to them. I am having trouble returning the correct type. I want an object list to be able to work with in my code to populate grids and such.

Can someone please check out my code and tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
public Customers_GetList_Result GetList(string CustomerName) {
    using (var db = new DataEntities()) {
        return db.Customers_GetList(CustomerName);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult' to 'DAL.Customers_GetList_Result'

Answer (score 2):

Hmm I think I figured out what I want:

```
public IEnumerable<Customers_GetList_Result> GetList(string CustomerName) {
   using (var db = new DataEntities()) {
       return db.Customers_GetList(CustomerName);
   }
}
```

I forgot to add `IEnumerable` to my function declaration. Sorry coming from VB.net to C#.

Answer (score 0):

The generated stored procedure returns [`ObjectResult<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739113%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`ObjectResult<T>` is a collection. If you want to return a single element of type T, you need to do as follow.

```
public Customers_GetList_Result GetList(string CustomerName) {
    using (var db = new DataEntities()) {
        return db.Customers_GetList(CustomerName).Single();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2272527, show your `Customers_GetList_Result` class and update it in the question

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when calling a function mapped to a stored procedure that I wanted to return a complex data type. I only got it when selecting a single record, and the suggestion above helped. The original code was:

```
        using (ede = new EDEntities())
        {
            var item = ede.SelectMatrixItem(itemCode);
            return item;
        }
```

When I changed it to:

```
using (ede = new EDEntities())
            {

                var item = ede.SelectMatrixItem(itemCode).FirstOrDefault();
                return item;
            }
```

then the error went away. My question is whether the FirstOrDefault or the SingleOrDefault is a better choice. The ItemCode is the primary key.

Joey